# Display number of user favourites / notifications

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am new to php and the mvc structure, however I am developing a library app for personal development. All is working as expected however I would like to implement one more feature - 'favourites'.

A notifications style bar contained within a `<div>`.

I currently have a `favourites` table that contains the following;

```
id    book_id    user_id
1     2422       22
2     6551       71
3     7716       22
```

What I am trying to do is simply display to the logged in user (eg user 22 above) *"Hello, you have **2** items in your favourites"*. I know this should be relatively simple and it would normally be, however the mvc format has me slightly confused.

I think I have the bulk of the work done I just need some direction and advice as to where I am going wrong. Is there something else I should be loading or including? How should I display the number of favourites within the `<div>`?

I have included my code below for reference.

**books_controller.php**

```
function checkFav()
    {
        $checkFav_model = $this->loadModel('Books');
        $checkFav_model->wishList();
    }

function itemView()
    {
        $itemView_model = $this->loadModel('Books');
        $this->view->books = $itemView_model->itemView();
        $this->view->render('books/itemView');
    }
```

**books_model.php**

```
public function wishList()
 {
    $userid=$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourite WHERE user_id = :user_id";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':user_id', $userid);
    $query->execute();
    $rows_found = $query->fetchColumn();//numRows doesnt work

     if(empty($rows_found)) {
        echo $rows_found;
    } else { 
        echo $rows_found;
    }
 }
```

**header.php**

```
<div class="notifications">
**DISPLAY NUMBER OF FAVS HERE**
</div>
```

Comment: Count the book by user id as the keywords. There is only one user with id 22 and has many book. So you count the book.

Comment: So what is the major problem ? first, with ur ori code above, you got the correct count result? second, the problem how to display the result on certain element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(book_id) AS book FROM favourite WHERE user_id = :user_id";
```

Reason : User has many favorite book. And your quote adbove

> "Hello, you have 2 items in your favourites"

so i think you want to showing how much book he likes. Not how many times he liked the book. But it can be done to with `SUM` on `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks, and what goes inside the <div> in my header.php?

Comment: The total book owned by user_id. If you ask how to implement the result, its depend on you. Using pure PHP or JSON string via `json_encode` on your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM favourite WHERE user_id = :user_id";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':user_id', $userid);
$query->execute();
$rows_found = $query->fetchAll();
$rows_found = $rows_found[0][count];
```

Comment: `<?php echo $rows_found; ?>`

Comment: Store the result on local variable and pass it to your view. Since this is custom code i think, i dont have knowledge about the method u use to pass the var from your model or controller etc.

Comment: So what the method to pass data to view. In CI its use `$this->load->view('my_view', $data)` in laravel `return View::make('my_view')->with('data', $data)` so by this method we know on our view we are looking for variable `data` to receive the data send by controller.

Comment: Great, did you figure it out? maybe you can choose one from two answer ? which one is you prefer.